# Do you need consent for Google Drive RestAPI if i am trying to use my own Drive?

Tags: javascript, rest, google-drive-api

I am trying to make a Google Drive Hierarchy Crawler for friends such that They can visit my website and look at files (instead of hosting them on my server).

I figured this could be a fun way to cut down on file transfers from my server by outsourcing it to a preexisting system.

I have a folder_id that i will pass into `gapi.client.drive.children.list` which will read out my files / folders.

The issue is that since this is entirely related to my files (which i have set public if they have the link), why do i need to have them authorize and consent their own drive?

I dont want my buddies to think i am getting into their stuff.

Some Code:

```
var CLIENT_ID= "-my-google-rest-api-key";
var ROOT_FOLDER = "folder-id";
gapi.auth.authorize(
  {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
    'immediate': true
  }, handleAuthResult);

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadDriveApi();
    } else {
      // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
      // clicking authorize button.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }
function loadDriveApi (){
  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', listFiles);
}
function listFiles (){
  var request = gapi.client.drive.children.list({folderId:ROOT_FOLDER});
}
```

Since the RootFolder is predefined, could i getaround everything and do something like:

```
gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', listFiles);
loadDriveApi();
```

I dont know how long cookies last.  Seems like once i authorized, i have yet to get it to ask me to authorize again.

For Reference:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children

Comment: From my experience, there is no way to get around the authentication. This needs to happened at least once, so your application can access user's data using a Google API. On the other hand, if you're looking to not have user give consent each time, take a look at [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline).

Comment: I feel they shouldnt need consent if they are accessing someone elses folder structure.  Ex:   My folder system is Public as long as people have the link, so i have issues believing required consent.